# PHP shell_exec issue with OpenCV exec (MAMP library error)

Tags: php, c++, opencv, mamp

I am trying to run an OpenCV executable with `shell_exec`in a simple PHP file. When I run the executable in the terminal it just prints out statements so it looks like this:

```
 Method [0] Perfect, Base-Half : 1.000000, 0.999990 
 Method [1] Perfect, Base-Half : 0.000000, 0.018286 
 Method [2] Perfect, Base-Half : 1.260779, 1.225753 
 Method [3] Perfect, Base-Half : 0.000000, 0.052663 
Done
```

But when I try to get the same output with php nothing shows up. I have tried playing around with other executables which aren't OpenCV and they work fine with the `shell_exec` but when I use an OpenCV executable nothing shows up.

Heres my php file:

```
<?php
$argv = "./OpenCV\ Test IMGS/oranges1.jpg";
$test=shell_exec($argv);
echo $test;
```

The `$argv` variable is what I type in the terminal in the same directory and gives me the output I wrote above. 
My OpenCV code looks like this:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat src_base, hsv_base;
  Mat hsv_half_down;

  /// Load three images with different environment settings
  if( argc < 2 )
    { printf("** Error. Usage: ./compareHist_Demo <image_settings0> <image_setting1> <image_settings2>\n");
      return -1;
    }

  src_base = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  /// Convert to HSV
  cvtColor( src_base, hsv_base, CV_BGR2HSV );

  hsv_half_down = hsv_base( Range( hsv_base.rows/2, hsv_base.rows - 1 ), Range( 0, hsv_base.cols - 1 ) );

  /// Using 30 bins for hue and 32 for saturation
  int h_bins = 50; int s_bins = 60;
  int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

  // hue varies from 0 to 256, saturation from 0 to 180
  float h_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
  float s_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };

  const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };

  // Use the o-th and 1-st channels
  int channels[] = { 0, 1 };

  /// Histograms
  MatND hist_base;
  MatND hist_half_down;

  /// Calculate the histograms for the HSV images
  calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_base, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
  normalize( hist_base, hist_base, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  calcHist( &hsv_half_down, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_half_down, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
  normalize( hist_half_down, hist_half_down, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  /// Apply the histogram comparison methods
  for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
     { int compare_method = i;
       double base_base = compareHist( hist_base, hist_base, compare_method );
       double base_half = compareHist( hist_base, hist_half_down, compare_method );

       printf( " Method [%d] Perfect, Base-Half : %f, %f \n", i, base_base, base_half );
     }

  printf( "Done \n" );

  return 0;
 }
```

I have checked my error logs and I don't get a PHP error but I do get another error in my console, I'm not sure what it means though. Heres what it says[image]

It would be great if someone could please explain to me what this error is and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some googling I managed to find what was wrong. It appears as though MAMP changes its environmental variable path. I am not too sure what this is but anyone who has a better knowledge of it please be my guest to explain it to others. Anyway I just had to comment out the two `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` lines and that resolved my error.

Heres the [webpage](http://jonathonhill.net/2012-06-22/cannot-run-a-binary-executable-from-php-and-mamp/) I used to help me.